# Arquivo Existe PHP

Tags: php, arquivo

estou usando esta função para verificar se o arquivo existe:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    //header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

    $nome_real = $_FILES["Arquivo"]["name"];
    $pastadestino = "/pasta/$nome_real";

    //verifica antes de passar - para apagar o existente
    if (file_exists($pastadestino))
    {
        echo "OK";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "NOK";
    }
?>
```

Porém, ele retorna OK mesmo se eu deixar o caminho vazio. Ou até mesmo se o nome do arquivo for diferente, alguem poderia me explicar?

Comment: Parece tudo certo pra mim... aqui deu `NOK`, veja no [ideone](https://ideone.com/Y6eXl3).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Pegadinha do malandro 1:

A função [`file_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-exists.php), apesar do nome, verifica se o caminho existe, independente dele ser um arquivo ou diretório.

Quando você deixa o parâmetro vazio, seu teste é o mesmo que isso:

```
if (file_exists( '/pasta/' ))
```

o que deve retornar verdadeiro caso a pasta realmente exista.

**Solução:**

A solução seria trocar a função por [`is_file()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.is-file.php), que é especifica para arquivos:

```
if (is_file($pastadestino))
    {
        echo "OK";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "NOK";
    }
```

Se quiser verificar pastas/diretórios apenas, há a função análoga [`is_dir()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.is-dir.php), que verificar se o caminho existe e é diretório.

```
if (is_dir($pastadestino))
    {
        echo "OK";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "NOK";
    }
```

### **Pegadinha do malandro 2:**

Cuidado se precisar fazer a verificação em arquivos logo após a mudança de algo no filesystem, pois todas as funções acima têm um *cache* no PHP.

**Solução:**

Para ter certeza de estar lidando com o caminho atualizado, existe o [`clearstatcache()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.clearstatcache.php):

```
clearstatcache(); // Limpamos o cache de arquivos do PHP
if (is_file($pastadestino)) // is_dir() para pastas, is_file para arquivos.
    {
        echo "OK";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "NOK";
    }
```

Clique nos nomes das funções acima para saber mais detalhes, eles estão *linkados* com a documentação online do PHP.

Comment: então se eu atualizar meu arquivo .php e por desta forma, ele vai verificar se o arquivo identificado no caminho é válido ou não?

Comment: Depende o que você chama de válido. Da forma que eu pus, é para verificar se o arquivo no caminho fornecido existe ou não. Se não funcionar, precisa verificar se o valor da variável está correto. Para pastas, is_dir(). Para arquivos, is_file().

Comment: OK, é isso mesmo, obrigado Bacco.